# C++ count different numbers given

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

The program has to count different numbers from standard input. For example, when input

```
6 <- how many numbers
1
3
1
4
3
786345
```

it should give out

```
4
```

Here is my sollution, although its too slow.
Is there aby faster way?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> occured; //vector of numbers that occured already

/*
    int findType(int find)
    finds where given number should be, I want to keep this array sorted.
    in case of number existed already return -1; otherwise return the index for inserting.
*/
int findType(int find) 
{
    for (int i=0; i<occured.size(); i++) //for each number in occured array
        if (find==occured[i]) return -1; //if it is same return it occured
        else if (find<occured[i]) return i;
    return occuerd.size();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int n; // read how many numbers will be given
    cin>>n;
    int tmp; //temp variables.
    int tmp2; 

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) //for each number
    {
        cin>>tmp;       //get it
        if ((tmp2=findType(tmp))!=-1)  //check if it occured
           occured.insert(occured.begin()+tmp2,tmp); // if not add it to occured vector.
    }
    cout<<occured.size(); //print how many different numbers

    //system("PAUSE"); //uncomment if needed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck - I think it's how many unique numbers were provided: `[1, 3, 4, 786345]`

Comment: @birryree: There we go, the question was edited, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, use `push_back()` to insert the input into the
`std::vector`.  Once you have all of the input, use `std::sort` and
`std::unique` on the vector.  Something like:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int nextValue;
while ( std::cin >> nextValue ) {
    numbers.push_back( nextValue );
}
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
int results = std::unique(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()) - numbers.begin();
```

Answer (score 6):

How about using `std::set` instead of `std::vector`? It will ensure no entry exists twice (you don't have to check that; it will be sorted as well), plus you just have to get the size to learn the number of different elements.

Example:

```
std::set<int> occured;
int tmp;
int n = 10; // or input it

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cin >> tmp;
    occured.insert(tmp);
}

cout << occured.size();
```

Comment: Interesting. Im a bit STL newbie, so can you briefly explain how to do that? I just ask for helpfull functions not for ready source. +1

Comment: `set`... +1. I was going to suggest a `map`, but `set` is precisely what's needed in my opinion.

Comment: I would only add that this is a reasonable catch-all solution and a good default if we are not handling a scenario with distinct characteristics.

Comment: But `std::set` is overkill. It does lots of extra things which is not needed here. `std::vector` along with a free function `bool exists(std::vector<int> const &v, int item)` would be a better choice..... Read this : [Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead)](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flafstern.org%2Fmatt%2Fcol1.pdf&ei=KwJyT4z8EsWoiAfI5f3jDw&usg=AFQjCNEOAgURQSrd8Z8uBzP3m6l6Yd3qwA&sig2=jHU-n4cAftRLFZDhY6QxEA)

Comment: @kittyPL You can see a good insert example at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/

Comment: It works like any of the other STL containers (as far as possible); adding a snippet.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm not sure about that. I would think that `set` is implemented as a kind of hashing function, which would give you constant time inserts. At best with a `vector`, wouldn't you need log time to do a binary search to see if the element already existed?

Comment: @aardvarkk: It is an interesting read : [Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead)](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flafstern.org%2Fmatt%2Fcol1.pdf&ei=KwJyT4z8EsWoiAfI5f3jDw&usg=AFQjCNEOAgURQSrd8Z8uBzP3m6l6Yd3qwA&sig2=jHU-n4cAftRLFZDhY6QxEA)

Comment: @aardvarkk - no hashing function for `std::set`, that's what `std::unordered_set` is. But it is faster for look ups (it has ordering) and already guarantees uniqueness of elements, though you get some overhead with how it stores elements. It's a tradeoff thing. `std::unordered_set` hashes, doesn't order, and has fast lookups.

Comment: @kittyPL - you have to tell us what 'Still too slow' means for you. Is your data set a billion numbers?

Comment: @kittyPL: What is `TOO SLOW`? How do use measure it? How many items you insert?

Comment: @kittyPL 1 million elements? Try `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: The James Kanze answer was great. It took less than second to happen with 1mln elements wooho :D